# how to show $c=0$,$f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=1$,

Tags: real-analysis

$f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=1$, $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f'(x)=c$   we need to show $c=0$

well, I tried like this $|f(x)-1|<\epsilon\forall x>M$, where $M$ is very large, $|f'(x)-c|<\epsilon\forall x>M$,  what more I can say?thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{1}$ exists, by L'Hospital

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{1}=c \,.$$

But the first limit is $0$.

**Alternately** Use the MVT on the interval $[x,2x]$. You have

$$\frac{f(2x)-f(x)}{x}=f'(c_x)$$

Now, when $x \to \infty$ we have $f'(c_x) \to f(c)$ and the LHS gos to $0$.

Comment: Why can you use L'Hopital's like this?  I thought you must have $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x)/g'(x)$ existing AND $f(x) \to \infty$ and $g(x) \to \infty$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Correct me if I am wrong, but in the proof of the $\infty/\infty$ case, we only use the fact that $g(x)$ goes to infty.

Comment: For example, check the proof from Wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#General_proof

Answer (score 0):

Yet another proof:

Let $0<x$. By the MVT in $(x,x+1)$:
$$\exists \xi\in (x,x+1):f'(\xi)=\frac{f(x+1)-f(x)}{x+1-x}=f(x+1)-f(x)$$
Letting $x\to +\infty$, $\xi\to +\infty$ and so
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}f'(x)=1-1=0$$

Comment: $\xi\to\infty$ ?

Answer (score -3):

If c isn't 0 then f is increasing/decreasing and can't converge to a limit.

Comment: Why? $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ has a limit at $\infty$....

Comment: @ N.S lim x-> inf (sinx/x)'=0. If f' does converge to a limit, it must be 0.

Comment: My point is that your reasoning is wrong. Namely this part:"f is increasing/decreasing and can't converge to a limit" is not true.

Comment: Yeah,you're right. I meant monotonically increasing(kind of). if f' conveges to c>0 then for all x>a f'(x)   >c-d for every d>0 so then we get f(x+b) >f(x)+b(c-d) if x>a aand hence f can't converge.  I didn't really wan't to be rigorous.

Comment: $\arctan(x)$ is increasing but it converge ;)

Comment: yeah, but the limit of f' at infinity is 0. so  the argument I made in the previous comment doesn't hold

Comment: Which part of "f is increasing/decreasing and can't converge to a limit" fails? That fact that my my example is a counterexample just for a step in your reasoning shows that that step is wrong.... not that the problem is wrong...